# Where is the default location of the directory in which PowerShell scripts are ran?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I ran a script in Powershell that was suppose to do some file analysis and create a csv.
It looks like it ran, and I didn't encounter any errors. 
My problem now is that I don't know where the file went!
Here is the script:

> Get-ChildItem \XX.XXX.X.XX\share -Recurse | Select-Object Name,
>   CreationTime, LastAccessTime, Directory, 
>   @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}} | Export-CSV
>   XXXXXXXXX.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your user directory, for example if I as duDE execute this script I'll find it in `C:/Users/duDE/XXXXXXXXX.csv` :

```
Get-ChildItem | Export-CSV XXXXXXXXX.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! It was there (: HOWEVER, I noticed that it was ALSO sitting right on my C:\ Do you know why??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - but we've found it!